# Socket.io and JS DOM compatibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a `socket.io` server that works, and that returns a number from 1 to 10 every second, that's the content of `message`.
But when I want to do dynamic content, it does not work, and the `div#para` stays on `connection ..`.
This does not come from the exchange of data, since when I replace the line `Document.get ...` with `alert (message)`, it works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Socket.io</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Communication avec socket.io !</h1>
    <div id='para'>Connection..</div>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            Document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = message;
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Document` should be `document` where you are setting the innerHTML property.

**Why**

`Document` [is a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

`document` is a global object.

The method `getElementById()` is only available on the global `document` object. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Notes).